# Is there a P2P framework in c?

Tags: c, frameworks, p2p

I try to implement some p2p functionality with c.
Is there any kind of framework?

What do you think taking libtorrent (http://libtorrent.rakshasa.no/) and do some adaptation there?

Or does anyone knows a good c framework/library?

Update 1:
More precise: i'd like to share small packages of data (metadata) between peers. The data packages should be distributed to every peer (every peer should have every data package).

Thanks

Comment: Please define the type of application you want to enable with your P2P framework.

Comment: The BitTorrent protocol is designed for large files, as it depends on servers (tracker) to hold information (torrent files) about the shared files. It would not make sense to share many small packages over BitTorrent, because each small package of yours would need a metadata file on the tracker. Have a look at Flooding/Gossiping instead http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gossip_protocol

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Chimera is the successor to Tapestry, one of the original 4 P2P overlay networks (along with CAN, Pastry, and Chord).  It's written in C: http://current.cs.ucsb.edu/projects/chimera/

Note that this is a base-level overlay network that you can build other stuff on top of (like messaging or file sharing).

Comment: So did you implemented successfully your application using this library?

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to simulate P2P then this link(P2PSim) might be helpful
http://pdos.csail.mit.edu/p2psim/